# cast not valid when using backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have moved my codes from Form_Load to BackgroundWorker but it says    'Specified cast is not valid' , Uploaded Here : [My Codes Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4ujE.png)

```
    Private Sub FirstRunWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles FirstRunWorker.DoWork
    Dim url1 As String = publicurl & "index.php"
    Dim datavillages1 As String = TGet("", url1, url1, My.Settings.useragent)
    If datavillages1.Contains("error") Then
        'ADD LOG
    Else
        wb.DocumentText = datavillages1
        While wb.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
    End If
End Sub
```

in main its work but in backgroundworker not , thanks for help

Comment: What is `Tget`? What is `wb`? What type is `wb.ReadyState`? What type is `WebBrowserReadyState.Complete`? Why are you using `DoEvents`?

Comment: Tget is my function , wb is my webbrowser control , my problem is i have not any access to my webbrowser control , i cant get page source and other things!

Comment: **DON'T EVER** use `Application.DoEvents()` in a loop as an attempt to keep your UI responsive! _**Especially not**_ in a `BackgroundWorker` or background thread! `DoEvents()` is a bad hack as it is always used incorrectly, and only causes more problems than it solves. It is entirely possible that the exception does not occur in your background worker at all, but in an entirely different place within your application, as `DoEvents()` forces the app to process all current messages here and now.

Comment: The one and only correct way of waiting for a webpage to finish loading is to subscribe to the [`WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted). Controls are generally not designed to be waited for in a single point in code, as that would normally freeze the UI. That's why they use events to let others react to changes.

Comment: You can't use a WebBrowser control from a thread other that the UI Thread. Not in these terms. Use its `DocumentCompleted` event if you need to wait for the HTML page to load and then do something with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your helps and answers , I fixed my problem with invoke !
now i can access any controls and functions

```
    Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Function()
'dosomething
                                        End Function))
```